# Subversion Warning Message when trying to commit change to branch

Tags: svn

I created a branch in subversion by copying the trunk directory.   But now when I commit changes to the branch I get this warning message: "Your working copy points to ... which appears to be a tag!  You should first switch to a branch or the main trunk before committing."

If I just ignore the error message and save to the target directory, the change appears to take but what is up with the warning message?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: Is there any way to suppress this message?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have created a trunk directory, and thats where all my code is.  Now I want to crate branches and tags.  So the first thing to do is to add and commit a tags and branches directory, but get this same error, and dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I've also experienced this; however, i was still allowed to commit the changes anyway. Wondering if this issue was actually resolved by SVN themselves in a patch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Guess: you are using TortoiseSVN and your working copy SVN URL contains the string `tags`.

See also: http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/dce8ddf63d0c66a6

Comment: I have a similar problem. It appeared after adding Boost sources + some libs. No "tags" in SVN URL.

Comment: Yes, committing source pulled from github that included an empty /tags directory to a local repo using TortoiseSVN causes this warning. Omitting the empty /tags directory from the commit (probably ignore in the long run) gets rid of the warning message. Presumably all goes well if you decide that you want the /tags directory as well.

Comment: Committing the tags directory (and contents) wasn't a problem.  Unfortunately, one of the Java EE 5 standards (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnana/index.html) is to place tag files in a tag directory, which trips up TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop TortoiseSVN looking for folders with these sensitive names and treating them differently by making a change in the general ToirtoiseSVN settings program.

- Load the settings program
- Click 'Revision Graph'
- Find the Classification Patterns / Tags box
- Delete the contexts of this box or change it's value